# Android WebView - when trying to play a YouTube video, screen is black but audio plays

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to play a YouTube channel from a WebView. It feels like I almost got it but I have two problems. Because there is some redirect when trying to load the YouTube channel url, the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method seems to be breaking things and I just get a gray screen.

And the other problem is that if I comment out that line and the Channel loads, when I play the videos, the video seems to load, and the audio plays, but the screen of the youtube stays black.

Here is my code

```
public class YoutubeActivity extends BaseActivity
{
    WebView webview = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   

    webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setInitialScale(1);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();


    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);        
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);



    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cache");
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases");


    webview.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/g33ktalktv");
```

Would anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: This has aways been my dream: to be able to play youtube video, but without having the screen on! This is going to spare so much battery! What you are faced with is not a bug, but major FEATURE!

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Actually - not quite. The screen still stays on. Just the rectangle of the YouTube screen stays black :(

Comment: any reason for not doing it the right way: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/ ?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Yes, I don't want to make remote api calls because they are https requests and I think it might take me a while to groc how to do the https async requests. This way is supposed to be quicker and cheaper.

Comment: And I am also not sure about the mobile youtube app - is that something extra people will have to download? If so, then that is terrible ux which people will hate

Comment: try this, for youtube with the screen off: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sherlock.drbradtech.com.sherlock